# Django failure with Eclipse

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I am trying to install a Django plugin with eclipse/pydev, and I get the following error message after an installation attempt.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Artifact not found: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.django_editor.feature,0.5.8.
http://eclipse.kacprzak.org/updates/features/org.python.pydev.django_editor.feature_0.5.8.jar
Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django_editor.plugin,0.5.8.
http://eclipse.kacprzak.org/updates/plugins/org.python.pydev.django_editor.plugin_0.5.8.jar
```

Anyone get this message before, or have the slightest clue what it might mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to note, that django editor is not the same one that's talked about in the PyDev homepage... PyDev does have a django editor integrated by default, which is made available when you install Aptana Studio 3 ( see http://pydev.org/download.html for details ). The Django version you're talking about ( http://eclipse.kacprzak.org ) was at one point integrated in PyDev but as Aptana Studio 3 evolved it's integration has been deprecated in favor of the one in Aptana Studio 3.